# Parsing Json using arduino-mqtt lib

Tags: c++, json, pointers, arduino

I am trying to use the arduino-mqtt lib.

I have this working sending the json string. The problem comes with trying to parse the string with ArduinioJson. It just returns no value.

I think it may have todo with the pointer reference in the mqttMessageRecived function ( **String &payload**).

Function called when there is an MQTT message:

```
void mqttMessageReceived(String &topic, String &payload){

//Example String for test

String json = "{"id" : "100" , "cmd" : "0xff"}";

jsonout(payload);

Serial.println("Sending Static String");
jsonout(json);
```

Function to parse json input:

```
void jsonout(String Json){

StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;

//Deserialize the JSON document
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, Json);
Serial.println("Got String: ");
Serial.println(Json);

// Test if parsing succeeds.
if (error) {
Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
Serial.println(error.c_str());
return;
}

const char* id = doc["id"];
const char* cmd = doc["cmd"];

// Print values.
Serial.println(id);
Serial.println(cmd);

}
```

**Non parsed output:**
Message from MQTT

```
Got String: 
"{\"id\" : 4 , \"cmd\": \"0xee\"}"
```

**Result = No output from json parse**

---

**Non parsed output:**
Sending Static String

```
Got String: 
{"id" : "100" , "cmd" : "0xff"}
```

**Result = Output from json parse:**

```
100 
0xff
```

Comment: The code is invalid or you copied it wrongly. The `json` string is not a valid C string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that - in the response from the server

> "{\"id\" : 4 , \"cmd\": \"0xee\"}"

the `id` field is an integer - not a character array.

So you need to change

```c
const char* id = doc["id"];
```

to

```c
int id = doc["id"];
```

(and update your test string to use an int for the ID also).

Comment: I have tried with both. Still no luck. Its as if the Json lib doesn't see the input from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The server returns a `id` member that's a `Number` `"id":4`, while you are generating a `id` that's a `String` `"id":"200"`.

You need to adjust your code to either one. If it's a number (and it seems so), you need to send `"id":200` and change your code to get a number:

```
unsigned id = (double)doc["id"];

// And to generate it:
String json = "{\"id\" : 100 , \"cmd\" : \"0xff\"}";
```

Also, with JSON, beware of hexadecimal encoding, has it's not converted to number (you have to do it yourself by receiving a `const char*` and calling `sscanf` or `strtol` or ...) and it's not convenient. It's better to use base-10 encoding instead:

```
String json = "{\"id\" : 100 , \"cmd\" : 255}";
```

Comment: Hi sadly this is not it. The json lib is some how not parsing the input. I have tried by ints and char.

Comment: If you've copied the output in the question exactly as it's coming, then you need to double escape the input JSON from the MQTT's `Json` before sending it for parsing (for now, simply call `Json = Json.substring(1, Json.length() - 1).replace('\\', '');`, but later, you need a proper backslash escaping).

Comment: Looking at the arduino-mqtt code, there is no encoding done in this code, so it's likely the MQTT publisher that's not sending correct JSON (double encoded JSON error here). So your code is somehow safe, you'll need to fix the MQTT sender. The MQTT payload message from the publisher should be `{"a": 3}` and not `"{\"a\": 3}"`